# Samsung Windows 8 memory leak, can't find reason

Tags: windows-8, memory, memory-leaks

[image: 1]

Does anyone know what the cause of this memory leak is? My memory shoots up every few days and I have to continually restart the computer. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Based on other forum posts, I've already deleted `Intellimem`. It helped a bit, but the memory leak still happens every few days (instead of every few hours).

Comment: You have 8Gb. Memory leak of that magnitude should be very conspicuous in **Task Manager** (<kbd>SHIFT+CTRL+ESC</kbd>) "Processes" or "Detailed" tab. Sort by the memory usage column and then look at the top.

Answer (score 0):

High modified memory is possible caused by [older Broadcom WIFI drivers](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/projectserver/en-US/7aaccf14-1636-46d9-8aec-952e6c6e1690/way-too-much-memory-takeup?forum=w8itproperf).  If your laptop uses a Broadcom Wifi adapter, update the drivers or [stop the BCMWLTRY.EXE from startup](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/15e91a76-31c1-46cd-9aa9-ff018226a7f9/pagefile-keeps-growing-until-i-run-out-of-memory?forum=w7itproperf) with msconfig.exe to fix it.